# Высота Label по высоте ячейки таблицы, когда текст в Label приходит позже рисования таблицы

Tags: swift, uitableview, label

Запнулся на ровном месте :(
Есть статическая таблица, в которой в одной из ячеек - Label. Необходимо выровнять высоту этой ячейки по высоте Label. Нюанс в том, текст появляется в метке позже, чем рисуется таблица и просто добавление строчек:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

во вьюДидЛоад не помогает.

Прикладываю весь код

```
   class EventTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  //Model
  var event: Event? { didSet {updateUI()}}
  var eventPlacemark: CLPlacemark? { didSet {updateUI()}}

  @IBOutlet weak var mapKit: MKMapView!
  @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!


  private func fetchTextAdress (){
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: event!.lat, longitude: event!.lon)) { [weak self] (placemarks, error) in
      if error == nil {
        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
          self?.addressLabel?.text = (placemark.addressDictionary!["FormattedAddressLines"] as!
            [String]).reversed().joined(separator: ", ") // Помещаю текст в Label
          self?.addressLabel?.sizeToFit() //делаю ресайз лэйбла 
        }
      }
      else {
        print (error!)
      }
    }
  }

  private func updateUI () {
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    fetchTextAdress ()
  }
}
```

Лэйбл имеет привязку ко всем границам ячейки.

Comment: Ви пробовали переместить в viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 0):

Как только текст пришёл и присвоен в `label`, можно вызвать `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_:withRowAnimation:)`, передав ей `indexPath` ячейки с лейблом. Если мне не изменяет память, это заставит таблицу пересчитать высоту нашей ячейки, не затрагивая остальные.

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите метод получающий высоту конкретной строки:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
        if (row == 10) // Номер вашей строки
        {
            return 150.0
        }
        return 90.0
}
```

А потом уже вызывайте tableView.reloadData() после того, как узнаете текст для заполнения label.
Не забывайте что текст надо присваивать в

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

В этой функции можете явно задать нужную вам высоту UILabel